# Endless pagination listview Android with database

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, pagination, infinite-scroll

I need to implement an endless pagination listview in my code, I've searched online and I saw a lot of examples, but none of them is using database, my app does the following:

it connects to an API and retrieves the data with json and show it in a listview, ok that works fine, but I want that listview to have an infinite scroll, like the facebook one.

I don't want anyone to write the code for me, I'm asking to someone guide me on wich is the better way to achieve that, I'll share some of my code, so you can understand:

```
try {
            //Repositorio is my database

            Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(getActivity());

            List listaDeClientes = mRepositorio.getClientes();

            System.out.println(listaDeClientes);

            TextView total = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.totalClientes);
            total.setText(getTotalClientes(mRepositorio.getTotalRegistros("clientes")));

            final ArrayAdapter ad = new ClienteViewAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_cliente_item, listaDeClientes);
            ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaClientes);

            lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);



            lv.setAdapter(ad);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

ClienteViewAdapter:

```
public class ClienteViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClienteModel> {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    private final int resourceId;

    public ClienteViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ClienteModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.resourceId = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ClienteModel mClienteModel = getItem(position);

        view = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

        TextView tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteId);
        TextView tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteNome);
        TextView tvTipo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienteTipo);

        tvId.setText(String.valueOf(mClienteModel.getClientes_id()));
        tvNome.setText(mClienteModel.getNome());
        tvTipo.setText(mClienteModel.getTipo());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class ClienteModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer clientes_id;
    private Integer id_rm;
    private Integer credencial_id;
    private String nome;
    private String tipo;
    private String informacao_adicional;
    private String _criado;
    private String _modificado;
    private String _status;

    public Integer getClientes_id() {
        return clientes_id;
    }

    public void setClientes_id(Integer clientes_id) {
        this.clientes_id = clientes_id;
    }

    public Integer getId_rm() {
        return id_rm;
    }

    public void setId_rm(Integer id_rm) {
        this.id_rm = id_rm;
    }

    public Integer getCredencial_id() {
        return credencial_id;
    }

    public void setCredencial_id(Integer credencial_id) {
        this.credencial_id = credencial_id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getInformacao_adicional() {
        return informacao_adicional;
    }

    public void setInformacao_adicional(String informacao_adicional) {
        this.informacao_adicional = informacao_adicional;
    }

    public String get_criado() {
        return _criado;
    }

    public void set_criado(String _criado) {
        this._criado = _criado;
    }

    public String get_modificado() {
        return _modificado;
    }

    public void set_modificado(String _modificado) {
        this._modificado = _modificado;
    }

    public String get_status() {
        return _status;
    }

    public void set_status(String _status) {
        this._status = _status;
    }

    public static String[] getColunas() {
        return Colunas;
    }

    public static void setColunas(String[] colunas) {
        Colunas = colunas;
    }

    public static String[] Colunas = new String[]{
            Coluna.CLIENTES_ID,
            Coluna.ID_RM,
            Coluna.CREDENCIAL_ID,
            Coluna.NOME,
            Coluna.TIPO,
            Coluna.INFORMACAO_ADICIONAL,
            Coluna._CRIADO,
            Coluna._MODIFICADO,
            Coluna._STATUS
    };
```

Comment: with a CursorWrapper class you can do it with 2 (sic!) lines of code (excluding boilerplate code for overriding methods)

Comment: @pskink Can you tell me more details about that?

Comment: override getCount() & moveToPosition(int position), each of them contains on line of code